# How to get data from url link itself

Tags: php

I have created a verification link which is being sent as an email to anyone who is registring to my site.

I want to be able to take data from url itself for example if the link is

```
http://localhost/verify.php?email=zeeshanahmed95@gmail.com?&activate=XacSwLp4xPuMm0yHE5i7h5kK8xBw0hN5
```

I want to extract data from URL from the part which is email and activate and store it in a variable in PHP.

Comment: can you please provide your code?

Comment: your Url wrong please check it first  it may be "http://localhost/verify.php?email=zeeshanahmed95@gmail.com&activate=XacSwLp4xPuMm0yHE5i7h5kK8xBw0hN5"  after email '?' it is not valid url

Comment: I have generated url in that pattern only. If it's wrong can you please help me with right pattern? @RahulPrajapati

Comment: Thanks @SwetaParmar I think $_GET function was what I was looking for as answered by nfn neil. I appreciate your assistance. Thanks.

Comment: please refer [php link] (http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php)

Comment: Thanks @RahulPrajapati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a built in $_GET variable set which should suit you fine.  Just comment if you need help.

```
$_GET['email']
$_GET['activate']
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. :)

Comment: Hey, if you could mark it as answer, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is just a string you have in data, then you can use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)...

```
$strURL = 'http://localhost/verify.php?email=zeeshanahmed95@gmail.com?&activate=XacSwLp4xPuMm0yHE5i7h5kK8xBw0hN5'
$arrVariables = array();
parse_str($strURL, $arrVariables);
echo $arrVariables['email'];
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I have found answer to my question. Thanks for your contribution I believe I can use this in another instances. Thank once again.